# SAPUI5 Retain pre selection on multiple rows?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have a table with `multiple-select` checkbox where I want to retain random selection, method `setSelectedRow(index)` overrides the previous selection.

Another method `setSelectedInterval(I,j)` but it's not random select.

Please help.

Comment: Is it a `sap.ui.table.Table`? Also, what do you mean by "random selection"? Do you want to randomly select a row in the table? Or do you just want to preserve all previous selections when adding a new one?

Comment: if you are referring to retaining the old selection and adding additional selection in a sap.ui.table.table, try using `table.addSelectionInterval(1,1);table.addSelectionInterval(4,4);`. This code will select row #1 and #4. If you required this, i will add it as answer so it can reach more community.

Comment: @Rahul, yes I've used the same and it worked and solved my issue. You can mark it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to retaining the old selection and adding additional selection in a sap.ui.table.table, try using:

`table.addSelectionInterval(1,1);
table.addSelectionInterval(4,4);`

This code will select row #1 and #4